# Is java Swingx (Swinglabs) a dead project?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I am not able to find an official site about it, just a github repository (https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/swingx) that point to http://swingx.dev.java.net/ that doesn't exists any more, all the links points to java.net.

What is the state of this project?  abandoned? dead? there is a new home that I can't find?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: You right, but I asked here because there are (were) some developers of the project answering questions here about it. I have no other ways to contact them. Using the [swingx] tag I was hoping a their answer.

Comment: What about putting a comment below some of their content? But again: being unable to contact project members is also an answer to your question...

Comment: How to moderate StackOverflow moderators?